# Cannot Deserialize XML correctly in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have looked at all the answers on here, I have tried absolutely everything however XmlSerializer is only partially serializing the XML into a C# class.

Here is my class:

```
[XmlRoot("User", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Online.Administration")]
public class User
{
    
    public string[]? AlternateEmailAddresses { get; set; }
    public string[]? AlternateMobilePhones { get; set; }
    public string? AlternativeSecurityIds { get; set; }
    public bool? BlockCredential { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public int? CloudExchangeRecipientDisplayType { get; set; }
    public string? Country { get; set; }
    public string? Department { get; set; }
    public bool? DirSyncEnabled { get; set; }
    public string? DirSyncProvisioningErrors { get; set; }
    public string? DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool? Errors { get; set; }
    public string? Fax { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? ImmutableId { get; set; }
    public string? IndirectLicenseErrors { get; set; }
    public bool? IsBlackberryUser { get; set; }
    public bool? IsLicensed { get; set; }
    public string? LastDirSyncTime { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? LastPasswordChangeTimestamp { get; set; }
    public LicenseAssignmentDetails? LicenseAssignmentDetails { get; set; }
    public bool? LicenseReconciliationNeeded { get; set; }
    public Licenses? Licenses { get; set; }
    public string? LiveId { get; set; }
    public string? MSExchRecipientTypeDetails { get; set; }
    public string? MSRtcSipDeploymentLocator { get; set; }
    public string? MSRtcSipPrimaryUserAddress { get; set; }
    public string? MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string? OathTokenMetadata { get; set; }
    public string? ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string? Office { get; set; }
    public string? OverallProvisioningStatus { get; set; }
    public bool? PasswordNeverExpires { get; set; }
    public bool? PasswordResetNotRequiredDuringActivate { get; set; }
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string? PortalSettings { get; set; }
    public string? PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string? PreferredDataLocation { get; set; }
    public string? PreferredLanguage { get; set; }
    public object? ProxyAddresses { get; set; }
    public string? ReleaseTrack { get; set; }
    public ServiceInformation? ServiceInformation { get; set; }
    public string? SignInName { get; set; }
    public string? SoftDeletionTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string? State { get; set; }
    public string? StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string? StrongAuthenticationMethods { get; set; }
    public string? StrongAuthenticationPhoneAppDetails { get; set; }
    public string? StrongAuthenticationProofupTime { get; set; }
    public string? StrongAuthenticationRequirements { get; set; }
    public string? StrongAuthenticationUserDetails { get; set; }
    public bool? StrongPasswordRequired { get; set; }
    public string? StsRefreshTokensValidFrom { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? UsageLocation { get; set; }
    public string? UserLandingPageIdentifierForO365Shell { get; set; }
    public string? UserPrincipalName { get; set; }
    public string? UserThemeIdentifierForO365Shell { get; set; }
    public string? UserType { get; set; }
    public string? ValidationStatus { get; set; }
    public string? WhenCreated { get; set; }

}

public struct LicenseAssignmentDetails
{
    public LicenseAssignmentDetail LicenseAssignmentDetail { get; set; }
}

public struct LicenseAssignmentDetail
{
    public AccountSku AccountSku { get; set; }
    public Assignments Assignments { get; set; }

}

public struct AccountSku
{
    public string? AccountName { get; set; }
    public string? SkuPartNumber { get; set; }
}

public struct Assignments
{
    public LicenseAssignment LicenseAssignment { get; set; }
}

public struct LicenseAssignment
{
    [XmlElement("DisabledServicePlans")]
    public object? DisabledServicePlans { get; set; }
    public string? Error { get; set; }
    public string? ReferencedObjectId { get; set; }
    public string? Status { get; set; }
}

public struct ServicePlan
{
    public string? ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string? ServicePlanId { get; set; }
    public string? ServiceType { get; set; }
    public string? TargetClass { get; set; }
}

public struct ServiceStatus
{
    public string? ProvisioningStatus { get; set; }
    public ServicePlan? ServicePlan { get; set; }
}

public struct Licenses
{
    public UserLicense UserLicense { get; set; }
}

public struct UserLicense
{
    public AccountSku AccountSku;
    public string? AccountSkuId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("GroupsAssigningLicense", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
    public object? GroupsAssigningLicense { get; set; }
    public ServiceStatus[]? ServiceStatus { get; set; }
}

public struct ServiceParameters
{
    [XmlElement("ServiceParameter")]
    public ServiceParameter ServiceParameter { get; set; }
}

public struct ServiceParameter
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public struct ServiceExtention
{
    [XmlElement("ServiceParameters")]
    public ServiceParameters ServiceParameters { get; set; }
}

public struct XElement
{
    [XmlElement("ServiceExtention", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/serviceextensions/2009/08/ExtensibilitySchema.xsd")]
    public ServiceExtention ServiceExtention { get; set; }
}

public struct ServiceInformation
{
    [XmlElement("ServiceInformation")]
    public InternalServiceInformation? InternalServiceInformation { get; set; }
}

public struct ServiceElements
{
    [XmlElement("XElement")]
    public XElement XElement { get; set; }
}

public struct InternalServiceInformation
{
    public ServiceElements? ServiceElements { get; set; }
    public string? ServiceInstance { get; set; }
}
}
```

Naerly all of the properties are populating.

The only propertis that are not populating are:

```
ProxyAddresses

ServiceInformation
```

ProxyAddresses will fill if I declare it as an object, but it fills it by putting in an Attribute and an Element so it's not tidy see:

[image: ProxyAddress]

And this is what ServiceInformation is giving me:

[image: ServiceInformation]

I've tried various things like adding [XmlArray("ProxyAddresses")] and [XmlElement("ProxyAddresses")] and making the property a string[] and object[] and just a string etc. I just cannot get it to serialize.

Here is the raw XML that needs to be serialized:

```
<c:ProxyAddresses xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d:string>SMTP:Rainier@M365B654613.OnMicrosoft.com</d:string>
</c:ProxyAddresses>
```

---

```
        <c:ServiceInformation>
          <c:ServiceElements xmlns:d="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml.Linq">
            <d:XElement>
              <ServiceExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/serviceextensions/2009/08/ExtensibilitySchema.xsd">
                <ServiceParameters CachePolicy="PerUser">
                  <ServiceParameter>
                    <Name>SPO_MySiteUrl</Name>
                    <Value>https://m365b654613-my.sharepoint.com/personal/emilyb_m365b654613_onmicrosoft_com</Value>
                  </ServiceParameter>
                </ServiceParameters>
              </ServiceExtension>
            </d:XElement>
          </c:ServiceElements>
          <c:ServiceInstance>sharepoint/*</c:ServiceInstance>
        </c:ServiceInformation>
      </c:ServiceInformation>
```

Comment: Can you please post the full XML?

Comment: Looks like you need `public List<XmlNode> ProxyAddresses {get;set;}`

Comment: @Charlieface the issue if I do that is i get an XmlNode object which is the same as when I just use object it plops an XmlNode object in there. I need it to put a string array of the proxy addresses

Comment: @Enigmativity seems it is way too big for me to do that

Comment: What about `[XmlArray(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")] public List<string> ProxyAddresses {get;set;}`

Comment: @Charlieface yep I tried that, anything that is already an existing answer here on stack overflow I tried.

This is the result of doing that: https://paste.pics/26429f920435e190af5de649dc0a140d

Comment: @yppaL - Put it on Pastebin then.

Comment: @Enigmativity ok here it is: https://pastebin.pl/view/5529f435 it is processed per <user></user>

Comment: @yppaL - You posted incomplete XML. It needs to be fully formed.

Comment: @Enigmativity grab a <User></User> that's what'[s being serialized at present. Everything infront/behind of that is discarded already

Answer (score 0):

What about this

used for xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<User xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Online.Administration">
    <c:ProxyAddresses xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <d:string>SMTP:Rainier@M365B654613.OnMicrosoft.com</d:string>
    </c:ProxyAddresses>
    <c:ServiceInformation>
        <c:ServiceElements xmlns:d="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml.Linq">
            <d:XElement>
                <ServiceExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/serviceextensions/2009/08/ExtensibilitySchema.xsd">
                    <ServiceParameters CachePolicy="PerUser">
                        <ServiceParameter>
                            <Name>SPO_MySiteUrl</Name>
                            <Value>https://m365b654613-my.sharepoint.com/personal/emilyb_m365b654613_onmicrosoft_com</Value>
                        </ServiceParameter>
                    </ServiceParameters>
                </ServiceExtension>
            </d:XElement>
        </c:ServiceElements>
        <c:ServiceInstance>sharepoint/*</c:ServiceInstance>
    </c:ServiceInformation>
</User>







using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            User user = (User)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }

    }
    public class User
    {
        public ProxyAddresses ProxyAddresses { get; set; }
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "ServiceInformation", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Online.Administration")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "ServiceElements", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Online.Administration")]
        public List<ServiceElements> ServiceElements { get; set; }

    }

    public struct ServiceElements
    {
    }
    public struct ProxyAddresses
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, It just creates an empty ProxyAddresses struct:

https://paste.pics/7de460f3100fef6af6f045cafc0ae3d0

Comment: I was more interest in getting the solution for ServiceInformation

Comment: because the ServiceElements struct is empty it does same as ProxyAddresses

Comment: ServiceElements is not null.  It is empty just because I didn't add any properties to the object.

Comment: yes and so because it has no properties it doesn't add anything and so doesn't solve my problem at all